# No newline character at end of file even after writing it

Tags: python

```
# Create strings for preparation of file writing
s = ";"
seq = (risd41Email, risd41Pass, rimsd41Email, rimsd41Pass);
textString = s.join(seq);

# Create file, write contents, move to usertxtfiles dir
with open(filename, "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(str(textString))
    text_file.write('\n')

os.rename(fileMigPath, fileDestPath)
```

I have the above code that clearly writes a newline to the file I am editing. When I try to use the file another script does not execute the line because there is no newline character at the end of the file. If I copy the file and then open it in vi and then save it, vi adds a newline character and the line of the file executes properly. If I run diff between the file that wasn't saved in vi versus the one that was I get the message that the difference is no newline at end of file. I am using Python 2.7.12 on Ubuntu server Xenial.

Comment: What is the output of `hexdump -Cv fileDestPath`?

Comment: hexdump as follows....
00000000  6d 69 6b 65 2e 6d 61 63  40 6f 6c 64 64 6f 6d 61  |mike.mac@olddoma|
00000010  69 6e 2e 6f 72 67 3b 6e  6f 74 61 70 61 73 73 77  |in.org;notapassw|
00000020  6f 72 64 3b 6d 69 6b 65  2e 6d 61 63 40 6e 65 77  |ord;mike.mac@new|
00000030  64 6f 6d 61 69 6e 2e 6f  72 67 3b 6e 6f 74 61 6e  |domain.org;notan|
00000040  65 77 70 61 73 73 0a                              |ewpass.|
00000047

Comment: As you can see, the newline is in there (the `0a` at the end). For reasons I have never understood, `vi` does not show the the last newline when editing a file. This [question about vi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19240082/why-do-gedit-and-vim-hide-the-final-newline-from-the-user) might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
    text_file.write('\n\n')
```

This should work!